# LINQ serialization

Tags: c#, .net, linq, serialization

Somewhere (I wish I knew where), Jon Skeet and Marc Gravel were thinking about working on a tool that translated a LINQ query to XML for transfer over the wire?  Does anyone know if they, or someone else has done this and made it public?

Scenario: distributed & cross assembly.  This is a nice to have feature for me at this stage.

Maybe this isn't possible yet.

Comment: I haven't. Pretty sure Jon hasn't. There are tools that do similar though - see asnwer by @polishchuk

Comment: Removed the link as I couldn't see anything connected with this topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take a look to [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673933.aspx).

> The WCF Data Services client library enables you to execute queries
>   against a data service by using familiar .NET Framework programming
>   patterns, including using language integrated query (LINQ).

It can translate LINQ queries, e.g.:

```
var selectedOrders = from o in context.Orders
    where o.Freight > 30
    orderby o.ShippedDate descending 
    select o;
```

will translated into following URI: `http://localhost:12345/Northwind.svc/Orders?Orderby=ShippedDate&?filter=Freight gt 30`

Comment: That's a great starting point.  I'll look into this some more.  Additional challenges: write a LINQ provider for a DB that doesn't have one.  I wonder if the LINQ expression tree can be accessed server side.  Thanks.